# Login issue even after correct password

Tags: ssh, login, password, putty, username

i am not able to login even after entering correct password and username may be due to the press of any wrong key, the error is: sorry that didnt work please try again error and the login page it is showing the login page again and again. i tried to login via root as well but failed

Comment: Is this for SSH or the Desktop? Ubuntu? Which version? A little specificity will make it much easier to offer a suggestion 

Comment: guest machine installed on host(windows)

Comment: There is still a remarkable lack of actionable information here ... 

Comment: It could be capslock or wrong keyboard language. If not, you have to [reset your password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).